# eliminate single character word in a list of sentence in pandas and numpy

Tags: pandas, list, pandas-groupby

I have a list of sentence as shown below

```
list_x = ['a b c d e f g', 'abc def ghi', 'ab c d e f gh i j', ' ab cd ef gh']
```

where each string which is separated by space is considered as word.

From the above list I would like to eliminate single character words and replace space with '-'.

Expected output:

```
x5 = ['abc-def-ghi' , 'ab-cd-ef-gh' ]
```

I tried below:

```
for item in list_x:
if (sum(len(x) == 1 for x in item.split(" "))) < 5:
x5.append(item.replace(' ','-'))
```

I would like to know is there any faster methods to  do the above.

Comment: It is column filled by lists?

Comment: No, it is just a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is use list comprehension here, if possible trailing spaces added `strip`:

```
list_x = ['a b c d e f g', 'abc def ghi', 'ab c d e f gh i j', ' ab cd ef gh']

L = [item.strip().replace(' ','-') 
     for item in list_x 
     if (sum(len(x) == 1 for x in item.split())) < 5]
print (L)
['abc-def-ghi', 'ab-cd-ef-gh']

L = [item.replace(' ','-') 
     for item in list_x 
     if (sum(len(x) == 1 for x in item.split())) < 5]
print (L)
['abc-def-ghi', '-ab-cd-ef-gh']
```

Comment: from the above output, how to avoid trailing '-'

Comment: @ALI - Use first solution, there is added `.strip()` in `[item.strip().replace(' ','-') `